# Search for Accented Characters

Tags: sql-server, diacritics

I've been looking around and I've found a lot of information regarding creating searches that are accent insensitive. This isn't what I'm after.

Some accented data is causing a problem in my UI and I'm looking to do some impact analysis.

Is there an elegant way to search a field for *any* accented character, other than unioning many different selects with different characters in each?

Answer (score 0):

The COLLATE clause changes the foo expression to allow you to GROUP BY separately

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (foo varchar(100));

INSERT @t VALUES ('bar'), ('bár'), ('xxx'), ('yyy'), ('foo'), ('foó'), ('foö');

SELECT
    foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, 
    MIN(foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS), MAX(foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)
FROM
    @t
GROUP BY
    foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
HAVING
    MIN(foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) <> MAX(foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS);
```

Or

```
SELECT
    foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    @t
GROUP BY
    foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The first one gives you some actual values rather than just a COUNT. But not all if you have several accented words

For SQL Server 2012, you can use this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM  
    ( 
    SELECT
        FIRST_VALUE(foo) OVER (PARTITION BY foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI ORDER BY foo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) AS safeFoo,
        foo
    FROM
        @t
    ) X
WHERE
    safeFoo <> foo
```

The 1st and 3rd rely on the sorting of non-accent characters before accented characters

Comment: I'm not trying to get a count of individuals. I just need a total count of rows where a particular column has an accented character.

Comment: Modify the 2nd one then. The use of COLLATE still applies.